# how to handle warning C4191: 'type cast' : unsafe conversion from 'int (__cdecl CWnd::* )(LPCREATESTRUCT)' to 'AFX_PMSGW'

Tags: c++, mfc, warnings

My solution is written in MFC (C++) and is migrate from maybe VC6. I also need to support 64-bit machines.

Now there is a warning in my MainForm, which is located in `MainForm.cpp`:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CMDIFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_CREATE() //C4191 warning
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

> C4191: 'type cast' : unsafe conversion from 'int (__cdecl CWnd::* )(LPCREATESTRUCT)' to 'AFX_PMSGW'

I dig into the `ON_WM_CREATE()` and I think this code is generated automatically by the project. They are below in `afxmsg_.h`:

```
#define ON_WM_CREATE() \
    { WM_CREATE, 0, 0, 0, AfxSig_is, \
        (AFX_PMSG) (AFX_PMSGW) \
        (static_cast< int (AFX_MSG_CALL CWnd::*)(LPCREATESTRUCT) > ( &ThisClass :: OnCreate)) },
```

I don't think I should modify this code, but how can I fix this warning?

By the way, I met the same warning when trying to add CWnd::OnCtlColor on my code. Below is the situation.

in MyDlg.cpp

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDlgSOProgram, CPropertyPage)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR() //add message map entry,C4191 warning
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

//function to handle STATIC control color change
HBRUSH MyDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    auto hBrush = CPropertyPage::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    if (
        nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_STATIC
        && pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_PS_CONNECTION_STATUS    
       )
    {
        if (this->m_bConnectError) {
            // Sets the font color as red when connection is failed.
            pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
        }
        else {
            // Sets the font color as blue in all other scenarios.
            pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 255));
        }
    }

    return hBrush;  
}
```

The code above also gets warning C4191.

warning C4191: 'type cast' : unsafe conversion from 'HBRUSH (__cdecl CWnd::* )(CDC *,CWnd *,UINT)' to 'AFX_PMSGW'

Does anyone have the idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Are you including `<afx.h>` in your source?  This warning is disabled in that header.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm if you think this warning is useless and make no sense, then I just can disable it using some other way. The point is I don't know whether I need to handle it or not.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting it at all, as the headers you should be including will disable it.  Is there something you're doing somewhere to re-enable that warning?  It is safe for you to ignore.

Comment: @Penny: Did you fix this? If so, then how? This warning is showing for me in a stock MFC solution without any modifications.

Comment: @c00000fd actually I have no good solution now, just disable this warning. #pragma warning(disable : 4191)